# opensource websites backend in java

Tags: java

Are there any opensource websites backend in java?
Just like reddit in python, and openstreet in ruby.

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean by "website backend"?

Comment: You probably mean "Are there any (big public) websites using OpenSource Java backends?". Can your please rephrase your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you're looking for a Java open source [CMS (Content Management System)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system)?

You can find here an overview of the most of them: [Open Source CMS in Java](http://java-source.net/open-source/content-managment-systems). Wikipedia also has an overview of some of them: [List of CMS in Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_content_management_systems#Java_2).

The popular ones are [Alfresco](http://www.alfresco.com/), [Nuxeo](http://www.nuxeo.org/) and [Liferay](http://www.liferay.com/). You can compare the detailed features on the [CMS Matrix](http://cmsmatrix.org/) site.

Comment: No, what he's looking for are websites which are both: open source  and written in Java ( at least the backend ) Like: StackOverflow.com is both: closed source and written in C# ? :P

Comment: @Oscar: He's asking for *existing* websites using an open source  Java-based backend? Well, the aforementioned CMS'es have a portfolio/client section where you can find companies who's using it. [Here is an overview of companies using Liferay](http://www.liferay.com/products/liferay-portal/stories). This is only not a real programming question, so the question would not belong here.

Answer (score 0):

[ThingLink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thinglink) is a finnish service with a custom build Java backend. The backend code is hosted on SourceForge.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean web frameworks? If so there are loads: http://java-source.net/open-source/web-frameworks

Edit: Tapestry 5 is great.